# Arrays Checking input

Tags: java, validation

So I'm trying to check input and if the entered integer is not greater than the previous one it should ask again. My program already checks if integer is out of bounds and if it's not an integer that is entered but it just doesn't check if the entered one is greater than the previous one.

```
for (int i = 0; i < finalGrades.length; i++){
    //check input is an integer
    while(!input.hasNextInt()){     
        System.out.print("Please enter integers only: ");
        input.next();
    }

    finalGrades[i] = input.nextInt();
    if(finalGrades[i] > 100 || finalGrades[i] < 0){     
        System.out.print("Please enter integers between 0 and 100 only:");
        finalGrades[i] = input.nextInt();
    }
    if(finalGrades[i] < finalGrades[i-1]){
        System.out.print("Please enter integers in ascending order only: ");
        finalGrades[i]= input.nextInt();
        continue;
    }   

}
```

Comment: my bottom if statement is not running properly.

Comment: Yes java. I just tagged.

Comment: Can you add the function that calls this code, and some example data?

Comment: `if(finalGrades[i] < finalGrades[i-1]){}` wouldn't you get an index out of bounds error when i=0 (your first iteration of the for loop)?

Comment: yes but it still doesn't work properly. I tried having i = 1; i <= list.length in the for loop

Comment: in what way is it not working properly?

Comment: it will ask for next integer and then in the end there will be a out of bounds error

Comment: well if you do `i=1; i<=list.length` you will still get array out of bounds...just at the end of the loop when you try to access `array[list.length]` rather than in the beginning when you try to access `array[0-1]` when i=0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you get any error?. any java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException?

What do you mean by "my bottom if statement is not running properly"?.

If this is your problem, see if below helps

When i=0

if(finalGrades[i] < finalGrades[i-1]) ==> if(finalGrades[0] < finalGrades[-1]), this will fail.

Here is the complete code.

```
    for (int i = 0; i < finalGrades.length; i++) {
        // check input is an integer
        while (!input.hasNextInt()) {
            System.out.print("Please enter integers only: ");
            input.next();
        }

        finalGrades[i] = input.nextInt();
        if (finalGrades[i] > 100 || finalGrades[i] < 0) {
            System.out
                    .print("Please enter integers between 0 and 100 only:");
            finalGrades[i] = input.nextInt();
        }
        if (i > 0) {
            if (finalGrades[i] < finalGrades[i - 1]) {
                System.out
                        .print("Please enter integers in ascending order       only: ");
                finalGrades[i] = input.nextInt();
                continue;
            }
        }
    }
```

thanks,

Comment: Yes I understand that.

Comment: I changed the for loop at the top to have (i = 1; i <= list.length; i++) and it still won't work

Comment: execute if(finalGrades[i] < finalGrades[i-1])  only when i>0, this will resolve your problem.

Comment: uhh no that won't do anything.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting an array out of bounds error in both cases where you use

```
    for(int i = 0; i < list.length; i++){}
```

and

```
    for(int i = 1; i <= list.length; i++){}
```

because in case one, at the beginning of your loop you will try to access array[-1] when `i=0` and in case two you will get an array out of bounds error when you reach the end of the for loop and `i=list.length` because the last index of your array is going to be `list.length-1` due to arrays starting at index 0.

The easiest solution I can think for your situation is to just put in a check and only do your comparison if `i > 0`

```
if(i > 0){
    if(finalGrades[i] < finalGrades[i-1]){
        System.out.print("Please enter integers in ascending order only: ");
        finalGrades[i]= input.nextInt();
        continue;
    }
}
```

Comment: Should I keep the i = 0 in the for loop?

Comment: I would recommend to keep using `for(i = 0; i < list.length; i++)`